# Android doubling number of touches?

Tags: java, android, touch

This android app is acting as if I had double tapped it each time I touch the screen, can anyone see why is this happening? I have it log "touch # " + [the number of touches] and it does "touch 1" and "touch 2" at the same time, same as "touch 3" and "touch 4"

```
package com.example.mondrianmaker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int width, height, x, y, color, touch;
    ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles, childsRect;
    Bitmap bg;
    Canvas canvas;
    Display display;
    LinearLayout ll;
    Point size;
    Paint paint;
    Random rn;
    Rectangle parentRect;
    TextView text, info;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //***FULL SCREEN***
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //---FULL SCREEN---

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;

        paint = new Paint(); //paint to color rectangle OBLI

        bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bg);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mondrian);

        rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coordinates);
        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        parentRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 480, 800); //create super parent rectangle
        rectangles.add(parentRect);                             //add super parent rectangle to list
        touch = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //Get Coordinate
        x = (int) event.getX();                 
        y = (int) event.getY();

        //set text view to clicked coordinates and number of rectangles on list
        text.setText(x + ", " + y + "      rectangles: "+rectangles.size());

        //set rectangle color *randomly
        setColor();
        paint.setColor(color);

        //get rectangle clicked
        parentRect = getRectParent(x, y);

        //make children of rectangle clicked
        childsRect = makeChilds(parentRect, x, y);
        addChildsToRectanglesDeleteParentRect(childsRect, parentRect);

        //check on childs
//      text.setText(childsRect.get(0) + " " + childsRect.get(1));

        //get onTouch action
        switch (event.getAction()) {
//      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//          text.setText(x + ", " + y);
//          ll.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bg));
//      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
//          ll.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bg));
//          System.out.println("22222");
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch++;
            Log.i("info", "touch # " + touch);
//          ll.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bg));
//          System.out.println("33333");
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void addChildsToRectanglesDeleteParentRect(ArrayList<Rectangle> childsRect, Rectangle parentRect){
        rectangles.remove(parentRect);
        rectangles.add(childsRect.get(0));
        rectangles.add(childsRect.get(1));
        int i = 0;
        Log.i("info", "length= "+rectangles.size());
        for(Rectangle e : rectangles){
            Log.i("info", i+"--> "+ e.toString());
            i++;
        }

    }

    public ArrayList<Rectangle> makeChilds(Rectangle parent, int x, int y){
        ArrayList<Rectangle> defaults = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
        defaults.add(new Rectangle(0,0,240,800));
        defaults.add(new Rectangle(240,0, 480, 800));
        ArrayList<Rectangle> childs = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
        for(Rectangle rect : rectangles){
            if(x>=rect.getX1() && x<=rect.getX2() && y>=rect.getY1() && y<=rect.getY2()){
                childs.add(new Rectangle(rect.getX1(), rect.getY1(), rect.getX2()/2, rect.getY2()/2));
                childs.add(new Rectangle(rect.getX2()/2, rect.getY2()/2, rect.getX2(), rect.getY2()));
            }
        }
        if(childs.size()>0){
            return childs;
        }else{
            info.setText(x + ", " + y + " " + parent + "no childs for this parent");
            return defaults;
        }

    }

    public Rectangle getRectParent(int x, int y){
        for(Rectangle g : rectangles){

            if (x > g.getX1() && x < g.getX2() && y > g.getY1() && y < g.getY2()){
                info.setText(info.getText() + "\n " + g.getX1()+"_x=" + x +"_"+g.getX2() +"\n"+g.getY1()+"_y="+y+"_"+g.getY2());
                return g;
            } 
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void setColor(){
        rn = new Random();

        switch ((int) Math.floor(rn.nextDouble() * 5)) {
        case 0:
            color = Color.BLACK;
            break;
        case 1:
            color = Color.RED;
            break;
        case 2:
            color = Color.YELLOW;
            break;
        case 3:
            color = Color.WHITE;
            break;
        case 4:
            color = Color.GREEN;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and works without any issue however you can try  using if statement. Also make sure your switch statement return true or break; tho it works without using any of them; here how you can use if statement:

```
 if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
           // up is called
           touch++;
           Log.i("info", "touch # " + touch);
           return true;
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably getting an `ACTION_DOWN` and an `ACTION_MOVE` and counting both.

Try moving your `++` to inside the switch case for `ACTION_DOWN`.

Comment: actually I put it inside the ACTION_UP case and still counts it twice.

Comment: None of your cases have `break`s.